# Split string to fixed length chunks and write in separate line in Raku

Tags: string, raku, rakudo

I have a file `test.txt`:

```
Stringsplittingskills
```

I want to read this file and write to another file `out.txt` with three characters in each line like

```
Str
ing
spl
itt
ing
ski
lls
```

**What I did**

```
my $string = "test.txt".IO.slurp;
my $start = 0;
my $elements = $string.chars;
# open file in writing mode
my $file_handle = "out.txt".IO.open: :w;
while $start < $elements {
    my $line = $string.substr($start,3);
    if $line.chars == 3 {
        $file_handle.print("$line\n") 
    } elsif $line.chars < 3 {
        $file_handle.print("$line")
    }      
    $start = $start + 3;
}
# close file handle
$file_handle.close
```

This runs fine when the length of string is not multiple of 3. When the string length is multiple of 3, it inserts *extra newline* at the end of output file. How can I avoid inserting new line at the end when the string length is multiple of 3?

I tried another shorter approach,

```
my $string = "test.txt".IO.slurp;

my $file_handle = "out.txt".IO.open: :w;
for $string.comb(3) -> $line {
    $file_handle.print("$line\n")
}
```

Still it suffers from same issue.

I looked for [here](https://docs.raku.org/language/io#Line_by_line), [here](https://docs.raku.org/type/Str) but still unable to solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
spurt "out.txt", "test.txt".IO.comb(3).join("\n")
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Looks like I thought too much ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using `substr-rw`.

```
subset PositiveInt of Int where * > 0;

sub break( Str $str is copy, PositiveInt $length )
{
    my $i = $length;

    while $i < $str.chars
    {
        $str.substr-rw( $i, 0 ) = "\n";
        $i += $length + 1;
    }

    $str;
}

say break("12345678", 3);
```

Output

```
123
456
78
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is of course to use `.comb` and `.join`.

That said, this is how you might fix your code.

---

You could change the `if` line to check if it is at the end, and use `else`.

```raku
if $start+3 < $elements {
    $file_handle.print("$line\n") 
} else {
    $file_handle.print($line)
}
```

Personally I would change it so that only the addition of `\n` is conditional.

```raku
while $start < $elements {
    my $line = $string.substr($start,3);
    $file_handle.print( $line ~ ( "\n" x ($start+3 < $elements) ));
    $start += 3;
}
```

This works because `<` returns either `True` or `False`.

Since `True == 1` and `False == 0`, the `x` operator repeats the `\n` at most once.

```raku
'abc' x 1;     # 'abc'
'abc' x True;  # 'abc'

'abc' x 0;     # ''
'abc' x False; # ''
```

If you were very cautious you could use `x+?`.
(Which is actually 3 separate operators.)

```raku
'abc' x   3; # 'abcabcabc'
'abc' x+? 3; # 'abc'

infix:« x »( 'abc', prefix:« + »( prefix:« ? »( 3 ) ) );
```

---

I would probably use `loop` if I were going to structure it like this.

```raku
loop ( my $start = 0; $start < $elements ; $start += 3 ) {
    my $line = $string.substr($start,3);
    $file_handle.print( $line ~ ( "\n" x ($start+3 < $elements) ));
}
```

---

Or instead of adding a newline to the end of each line, you could add it to the beginning of every line except the first.

```raku
while $start < $elements {
    my $line = $string.substr($start,3);

    my $nl = "\n";

    # clear $nl the first time through
    once $nl = "";

    $file_handle.print($nl ~ $line);

    $start = $start + 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for multitude of approaches. Got to know `once` function.

Comment: @SumanKhanal Note that `once` is once per closure clone. Which is generally what you want it to do anyway. `for ^5 { for ^3 { once say 'hi' }}` says `hi` 5 times since the inner loop is cloned 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

*At the command line prompt, three one-liner solutions below.*

Using `comb` and `batch` (retains incomplete set of 3 letters at end):

```
~$ echo 'StringsplittingskillsX' | perl6 -ne '.join.put for .comb.batch(3);'
Str
ing
spl
itt
ing
ski
lls
X
```

Simplifying (no `batch`, only `comb`):

```
~$ echo 'StringsplittingskillsX' | perl6 -ne '.put for .comb(3);'
Str
ing
spl
itt
ing
ski
lls
X
```

Alternatively, using `comb` and `rotor` (discards incomplete set of 3 letters at end):

```
~$ echo 'StringsplittingskillsX' | perl6 -ne '.join.put for .comb.rotor(3);'
Str
ing
spl
itt
ing
ski
lls
```